# SharedPreferences value always returns true?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I have an Activity in which I am trying to implement a kind of auto-login. In my login activity, I have this:

```
sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
User.setUid(sharedPref.getInt("UID", 1));
Boolean al = sharedPref.getBoolean("AUTOLOGIN", false);

...

if (al) {
    Log.i("AUTOLOGIN", "Go!");
    Gui.createAlert(context, context.getString(R.string.loading));
    Intent i = new Intent(context, CityActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
...
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ...
       Ajax.AjaxListener callback = new Ajax.AjaxListener() {
          int uid = Integer.parseInt(userInfo.optString("user_id", "1"));
          String sid = user.optString("sid", "");
          String k = json.optString("k", "");
          Boolean al = autoLogin.isChecked();

          SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPref.edit();
          e.putInt("UID", uid).putBoolean("AUTOLOGIN", al).putString("SID", sid).apply();

          Gui.createAlert(context, context.getString(R.string.loading));
          Intent i = new Intent(context, CityActivity.class);
      };
});
```

I've only been able to test this on the emulator, and I can't seem to get the `SharedPreferences` file contents to show in Android Device Monitor, but every time the app loads, it does the autologin routine. Even when I shut down the emulator completely and restart everything the autologin flag seems to persist. I'm pretty new to Java/Android programming, but coming from a PHP and JavaScript background, it's not hard to pick up. I'm just stumped as to why the `AUTOLOGIN` `SharedPreference` key always seems to return `true` when checked. Is there an example of implementing autologin with `SharedPreferences`?

I should note that I tried to use a database originally, but scrapped the idea because of difficulty of use and the minimal data required right now.

Comment: commit sharedpref.

Comment: you need to uninstall or clear data of the app then only your preferences get clear

Comment: If you have some logout concept in your app use `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();editor.clear();` By this the content of SharedPreferences will be deleted and your auto-login will be stopped.

Comment: @santoshkumar apply also do the same work and OP is using that already

Comment: As @santoshkumar said when you successful login then change the login `boolean` value. you should do like this `SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPref.edit();
          e.putInt("UID", uid).putBoolean("AUTOLOGIN", true).putString("SID", sid).apply();` when you logout then `editor.clear();` and `editor.commit();` so your sharedpreferences will be clear saved data

Comment: you can editor.clear(); clear editor before putting values OnClickListener it will not have earlier value.

Answer (score -2):

*Try This Hope This Will Help You.*
*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void login(View v){

        SharedPreferences spf=getSharedPreferences("myprfs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name=spf.getString("uname", "no value");

        String pass=spf.getString("pass", "no value");      

        EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        if(et1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && et2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pass))
        {

            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class));
            startActivity(i);

        }



    }

    public void register(View v){

        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationActivity.class));
        startActivity(i);



    }

}
```

*RegistrationActivity.java*

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.register);

    }


    public void register(View v){

        EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


        SharedPreferences spf=getSharedPreferences("myprfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor spe=spf.edit();

        spe.putString("uname", et1.getText().toString());
        spe.putString("pass", et2.getText().toString());
        spe.putString("dob", et3.getText().toString());

        spe.commit();

        finish();   

    }
}
```